# Second SELECT getting an increasing incremental run when first SELECT is changed over and over

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have two `select` elements. The first (S1) controls a case type. The second (S2) displays when the first option (O1) of S1 is selected. S2 then hides when S1's second option (O2) is selected. For testing I have it writing to the console. Simple yes? I have that working no issues.

Problem is this ... when I choose S1>O1, then choose S2>O1 everything is fine as seen in the console. Then I choose S1>O2 and S2 hides. Which is also as expected. Then I choose S1>O1 again. S2 resets and displays as expected. BUT when I then choose S2>any option, the console shows that it incremented and is running S2's onChange event multiple times. Every time I switch between S1>O1 and S1>O2 the increment increases which eventually locks up the screen.

I have no idea why it is doing this. I'm probably missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Fiddle is below.

https://jsfiddle.net/wswilliams/a5qu1km6/

Thanks in advance.

```js
$("#fld_Severity").hide();

$("#fld_CaseType").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#fld_CaseType").children("option:selected").val() == 26) {
    $('#fld_Severity').val('0')
    $("#fld_Severity").show();
    $("#fld_Severity").on("change", function() {
      console.log("Severity looped.");
    });
  };

  if ($("#fld_CaseType").children("option:selected").val() == 30) {
    $("#fld_Severity").hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fld_CaseType" name="case_type" data-stop-refresh="true">
  <option value="0" selected>Select a case type ...</option>
  <option value="26">Case type 1</option>
  <option value="30">Case Type 2</option>
</select>

<select id="fld_Severity" name="severity_id" data-stop-refresh="true">
  <option value="0">Select a severity ...</option>
  <option value="4">Severity 1</option>
  <option value="3">Severity 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because every time your code runs the change event for fld_CaseType it is adding an additional event listeners for fld_Severity. so if you changed fld_CaseType 5 times you would have 5 event listeners listening for a change meaning the code would get executed 5 times (once for each event listener).

To fix this you need to remove any 'change' event listener from fld_Severity using the jquery [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function before adding a new one.

```
$("#fld_Severity").off("change");
```

I have created a working snippet below:

```js
$("#fld_Severity").hide();

$("#fld_CaseType").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#fld_CaseType").children("option:selected").val() == 26) {
        $('#fld_Severity').val('0');
        $("#fld_Severity").show();
        $("#fld_Severity").off("change"); //remove on change event listener 
        $("#fld_Severity").on("change", function() {
          console.log("Severity looped.");
        });
  }

  if ($("#fld_CaseType").children("option:selected").val() == 30) {
    $("#fld_Severity").hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fld_CaseType" name="case_type" data-stop-refresh="true">
<option value="0" selected>Select a case type ...</option>
<option value="26">Case type 1</option>
<option value="30">Case Type 2</option>
</select>

<select id="fld_Severity" name="severity_id" data-stop-refresh="true">
<option value="0">Select a severity ...</option>
<option value="4">Severity 1</option>
<option value="3">Severity 2</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively you could just move the event listener code outside of the change event for fld_CaseType so that it only ever gets called once

eg.

```
$("#fld_Severity").on("change", function() {
    console.log("Severity looped.");
});

$("#fld_CaseType").on("change", function() {
    if ($("#fld_CaseType").children("option:selected").val() == 26) {
        $('#fld_Severity').val('0');
        $("#fld_Severity").show();       
    }
    if ($("#fld_CaseType").children("option:selected").val() == 30) {
        $("#fld_Severity").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! That fixed it. Always something simple. I will keep your second example in mind in the future. Currently the real design is too complex to structure all the secondary calls without nesting them :/